# Sample Theme Options page for Multisite - what to consider

Tags: theme-development, multisite, theme-options

I used Theme Options page from the [Tutorial of Ian Stewart](http://themeshaper.com/2010/06/03/sample-theme-options/) in some of my WP site, and it works just fine. What I did externally was [this](http://tuts.nanodesignsbd.com/editors-to-access-and-save-theme-options/) (closest [English Tuts](http://ednailor.com/2012/04/16/allowing-non-admin-users-to-update-theme-options/)). All those sites were single sites. But now I'm dealing with a WordPress Network.

As I'm developing a single theme for all the sub-sites, I'm placing the `theme-options.php` into my theme as a common file. As per my search, I got a conditional statement:

```
global $blog_id;    
if( $blog_id == '1' ) {
   //do things for first site
}
```

Do I need to echo the same code of the `theme-options.php` under two such block to activate different thing in different site?
Or, do I need to made two different `theme-options.php` and conditionally load them for different site?

```
 global $blog_id;    
 if( $blog_id == '1' ) {
    require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/theme-options.php' );
 } elseif ( $blog_id == '2' ) {
    require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/theme-options-bengali.php' );
 } else {
    require_once ( get_template_directory() . '/theme-options.php' );
 }
```

Please note: Two of my site's settings, in many cases could be different and I'd need to grab them differently for the front-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could take advantage of [`get_template_part( $slug, $name )`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part) and use it like:

```
get_template_part( 'theme-options', get_current_blog_id() );
```

Say we are on `blog_id` 5, if *theme-options-5.php* exists it will be loaded. If not *theme-options.php* will be loaded as a fallback. Please note that `get_template_part` is using `require`.

Comment: I got an answer regarding `get_template_part()` and `require_once()`: [See here^](http://themeshaper.com/2010/06/03/sample-theme-options/comment-page-1/#comment-161339)